# Ada Compiler abandons Instantiation of package passing overloaded operators

Tags: operator-overloading, instantiation, ada

I want to instantiate a package and pass functions to it that overload operators in order to make a Generic Binary Search Tree. Here's the specifications.

*bstgen.ads (snippet)*

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;

GENERIC
   type Akey is private;
   type TreeRecord is private;
   with function "<"(K: in Akey; R: in TreeRecord) return Boolean;
   with function ">"(K: in Akey; R: in TreeRecord) return Boolean;
   with function "="(K: in Akey; R: in TreeRecord) return Boolean;

PACKAGE BSTGen IS

   TYPE St10 IS NEW String(1..10);
   TYPE TreePt IS PRIVATE;
   PACKAGE EnumIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(Akey); USE EnumIO;
```

*driver.adb (snippet)*

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
WITH BSTGen;

PROCEDURE Driver IS
   IP: Integer := 1;
   TYPE Names IS (Resig,Keene,Marsden,Vuijic,Marcus,Gonzalez);
   PACKAGE NamesIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(Names);
   type St10 is NEW String(1..10);
   type Customer is 
      record Name:  Names;  
      PhoneNumber: St10; 
   end record;
   function "<"(K: in Names; R: in Customer) return Boolean is begin
      return K < R.Name;
   end "<";
   function ">"(K: in Names; R: in Customer) return Boolean is begin
      return K > R.Name;
   end ">";
   function "="(K: in Names; R: in Customer) return Boolean is begin
      return K = R.Name;
   end "=";
   PACKAGE IntIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(Integer); USE IntIO;
   PACKAGE mybst is NEW BSTGen(Names,Customer,<,>,=); USE mybst;
   R, Pt: TreePt;
   Name: Names;
   Phone: St10;
   Status: Boolean;
BEGIN
   R := CreateTree;
   Pt := R;
```

However, when I try to compile, this is the output:

```
driver.adb:24:04: expect subprogram or entry name in instantiation of "<"
driver.adb:24:04: instantiation abandoned
bstgen.ads:19:53: expect discrete type in instantiation of "Enum"
bstgen.ads:19:53: instantiation abandoned
```

This includes a bunch of errors stating that driver.adb's methods are not visible, which is to be expected as the instantiation of mybst is abandoned. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `bstgen.ads`, you say

```
PACKAGE EnumIO IS NEW Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO(Akey);
```

but in the generic formal part you said

```
type Akey is private;
```

which means that the compiler can assume very little about the actual type except that equality and assignment are available. It could be a record of hundreds of bytes; it certainly need not be an enumeration.

To ensure that `Akey` is an enumeration, you need to say

```
type Akey is (<>);
```

as in [ARM12.5(13)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-12-5.html#p13).

In `driver.adb`, you say

```
PACKAGE mybst is NEW BSTGen(Names,Customer,<,>,=);
```

which should read

```
PACKAGE mybst is NEW BSTGen(Names,Customer,”<“,”>”,”=“);
```

Comment: thank you Mr. Wright, as long as I have your attention how do I define a type that must have x or y selectors in Generics?

Comment: Glad to help. If you have another problem, you should ask another question (with a bit more detail, please! “selectors”???)